# White spots when drawing circles in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was making some software in Pygame+TKinter and ran into something weird in pygame. When using parameter width=0 in pygame.draw.circle lots of small white spots are created. I do not want this in my program but i have no idea how to fix it, any solutions?

I have made a simple example of my problem.

```
import pygame

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

while True:
    window.fill((255,255,255))

    pygame.draw.circle(window, (0,0,0), (400, 300), 100, 5)

    pygame.display.flip()

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

(This gives me lots of white spots in the circle)

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this issue by drawing two circles:

```
pygame.draw.circle(window, (0,0,0), (400, 300), 100, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(window, (255,255,255), (400, 300), 95, 0)
```